# Most similar face recognition in Python

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

How can I use Python and OpenCV to find facial *similarity*?

I've successfully used OpenCV and Python to extract faces from multiple photographs using Haar Cascades.

I now have a directory of images, all of which are faces of different people.

What I'd like to do is take a sample image, and then see which face it most looks like.

I've tried using [pyssim](https://github.com/jterrace/pyssim):

```
pyssim needle.jpg "haystack/*"
```

But, unfortunately, it's looking a *image* similarity (colours etc) rather than facial features.

To reiterate - I'm quite happy detecting faces, what I'd like to be able to do is compare them.

Comment: [FaceRecognizer Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html)

Comment: This is a bit too big a question for Stack Overflow, unless you're expecting library recommendations (which as you know are off-topic).

Comment: @Veedrac Not necessarily. If for example someone knows a method in OpenCV to map faces to some kind of vector those could be compared rather easily. Would be a rather short answer and a good starting point for one owns approach

Comment: @Lord_Gestalter I'll give benefit of the doubt, but I'm still unconvinced.

Comment: I'd appreciate a little more specificity than "RTFM" :-) Besides, all those docs refer to is C++

Comment: Such mappings between faces and vectors exist, I just don't know if in OpenCV. Please have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSRA8GpWIrA

Comment: @Lord_Gestalter I'm quite sure that there isn't a single method in OpenCV that does measure the similarity of facial images. It might be done with OpenCV but would need programming effort on its own.

Comment: @TerenceEden Have a look in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface , I think that's the keyword you can build on