# Comparision of Faces for identification in Open CV & Python

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to make face identification security system.

I Used `Open CV` with Python.

I only can detect the faces from video and store them in my local Hard Drive.

but I want to `compare` the faces for identification of person like

```
while faces in my databse:
    if face="xyz":
        face is right
    if face is right:
        person is xyz
```

This is what I am looking for.

Comment: This seems similar to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203204/most-similar-face-recognition-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

This is the face recognition or face re identification, opencv offer the basic face recognition algorithm. You can also refer to some deep learning mathod such as [openface](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface)